# determining whether login was successful at MySpace

Tags: iphone, ios, callback, myspace

I am integrating MySpaceID iOS SDK to my application. I can login to MySpace from my app by opening a Safari login page, however, after returning back to my App from Safari, I could find where the callback function is.

I think that there should be some call back function which tells me if the login is completed or not. Where could I find that?

Answer (score 1):

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url . It is the callback function and you should write it in your appdelegate k. Once login it will come to this method.